# how to loop through a database table of numbers until you have sum of an input number php/sql

Tags: php, mysqli

So basically if you have a table in your database which looks like this:

id :: name :: numbers 
 1 ::: Jack ::::::: 4  
2 : Katrina ::::: 2
3 :: Clyde :::::: 8

I am looking to loop through the numbers column adding the numbers to each other until it reaches a certain number input and then echos out the one row, where the numbers has added up to.
So if your input is 3 it will output the row with Jack, if the input is 5 or 6 it will output Katrina and if the input is from 7-14 it will output the row with clyde. 
The thing here I cannot figure out is how i loop through the numbers column adding up the numbers until you reach a specific row, then to echo only that specific row out.

I know how to echo out all rows and creating the condition for the input field but I seem to be stuck at grasping how to go further.

```
    $sql = "SELECT medlemsid, navn, lotterinr, tid FROM medlemmer";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "| id: " . $row["medlemsid"]. " | - Name: " . $row["navn"]. " " ." | Lotterinr " . $row["lotterinr"]. " | Tid: ". $row["tid"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

if (isset($_POST['numberinput'])) {

            $numbers = $_POST['numberinput'];       

}

$con->close();
?>

<div id="udlodning-wrapper">

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" method="post">

        <div>
            <input name="numberinput" type="number" id="numberinput"  placeholder="Lotterinummer" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Udlodning" id="udlodning-submit" class="button-input"/><br/>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Why loop through and sum when you can just use `sum()` in the SQL query? Find a basic SQL tutorial to learn how to `group by` and use aggregate functions.

Comment: Do you need to sport the rows first?  Or do yo only calculate based on ascending id's?

Comment: you could look at it as each number is a lottery chance you have, I only need to calculate it so that I can either through a random generator sort through the chances and output a winner or choose a random number between the total chances and figure out which id and name has won

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use self join to find out **sum of number of people with id equal or less than current person**

```
select
  p1.id,
  p1.name, 
  p1.number, 
  sum(p2.number) as sum
from people p1
join people p2 on p2.id <= p1.id
group by p1.id, p1.name, p1.number;
```

SQL above would produce a result like this:

```
id  name    number  sum
1   jack    4       4
2   katrina 2       6
3   clyde   8       14
```

You can then iterate through the result, checking your input against sum

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually helped a lot for understanding and not being stuck :)